# If 12 dice are rolled, what is the probablity that the minimum value of the 12 dice is 2?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

Here is how I tried solving it:

- First we need to make sure that we do not roll any 1s in the 12 rolls: $(5/6)^{12} ≈ 0.1121$
- We also need to make sure that at least one of the rolls results in a 2 or higher. The probability of rolling a 2 or higher on a single roll is $5/6$. The probability of rolling at least one 2 or higher in 12 rolls is $1 - (1/6)^{12} ≈ 0.9999$.
- Therefore, the probability is $P = (5/6)^{12} \cdot 0.9999 ≈ 0.1121$, which is the wrong answer.

I looked at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692643/two-dice-are-rolled-what-is-the-probability-that-the-minimum-value-of-the-two-d) question previously asked, however all the answers seems to just use brute force to get all the values of the numerator because it only dealt with 2 dice. Any ideas on how to attempt to solve this problem would greatly be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $12$ rolls (text) or $6$ rolls (title)?  You want *all* the rolls to be $2$ or more, rather than *at least one* of the rolls.

Comment: why 'or higher'? if there are no 2s, the minimum can't be 2.

Comment: The second prob. should be of " at least one 2 given that none rolled 1".

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ be the minimum value seen among the twelve dice.

Recognize that $\Pr(X=2) = \Pr(X\geq 2) - \Pr(X>2)$

That is to say, to have the minimum value be exactly two... it must be the case that the minimum value is at least two while not being strictly more than two.  Further recognize that since we are dealing with whole number values here, the minimum being strictly more than two is equivalent to the minimum being at least three.

The probabilities $\Pr(X\geq 2)$ and $\Pr(X\geq 3)$ are found easily by just saying "All numbers are among 2,3,4,5,6" or "All numbers are among 3,4,5,6" respectively.

$$\Pr(X=2) = \Pr(X\geq 2)-\Pr(X\geq 3) = \left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)^{12}-\left(\dfrac{4}{6}\right)^{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

You got it right on the first point: no $1$s in all rolls,
but the second point is incorrect:

> At least one of the rolls needs to be $2$ or higher.

This is false. For example, you could have $12$ rolls of all $3$s:
no $1$s, at least one roll is $2$ or higher,
but obviously the minimum is not $2$.
The correct conditions should be

> No $1$s and at least one of the rolls is *exactly* $2$.

Because there are no $1$s, as long as there is at least one $2$, the minimum will automatically be $2$.
From this, we have the following calculation:
$$
\begin{align*}
P=\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{12} - \left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{12}.
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Fixing your mistake**

- Possibility that we do not roll any $1$s: $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{12}$, the same figure you have
- Possibility that you roll at least one $2$s if you don't roll any $1$s: $1-\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{12}$

So the answer is $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{12}\times\left[1-\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{12}\right]=\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{12}-\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{12}$. The same as other answers here

**Explanation**

If we know we do not roll any $1$s, there are only $5$ possible roll, not $6$ anymore. Consequently, the probability to have no $2$s is $\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{12}$ instead of $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{12}$

You may want to revise the conditional probability chapter